# sending large file along with file size through socket in android

Tags: android, sockets, filereader

earlier i transfer only video file over socket but when i require file size on the other end then problem occured,so i thought to send Object through Socket but there comes problem with file size limit.It transfer files upto size of 45MB however i want to transfer files of size more than that.
i have posted code below:

```
public class WiFiDirectBundle implements Serializable {
private String fileName;
private String fileType;
private Long fileSize;

ArrayList<byte[]> chunks;
ArrayList<Integer> a;
static int len=0;
byte[] buf;

public WiFiDirectBundle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException,
IOException {
    File f = new File(path);

    fileName = f.getName();
    fileType = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(f.getAbsolutePath());
    fileSize = f.length();
    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG,"name of file is"+fileName);
    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG,"size of file is"+fileSize);

    FileInputStream fin = null;
    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  



   fileContent = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    try {
        fin.read(fileContent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    fin.close();

}

// restores the file of the bundle, given its directory (change to whatever
// fits you better)
public String restoreFile(String baseDir) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(baseDir + "/" + fileName);
    File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
    if (!dirs.exists())
        dirs.mkdirs();
    f.createNewFile();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        if (fileContent != null) {
            fos.write(fileContent);
        }


        fos.close();
        return f.getAbsolutePath();

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think this `fileContent = new byte[(int) f.length()];` in your code might cause `Out of memory`. As you have declared `byte[] buf;`, why not use a buf instead?

Comment: could u pls elaborate it with n xampl 
that would b nice of u 
thank u

Comment: You can try some code like this: `buf = new byte[1000];
   while(fis.read(buf) != -1){
    fos.write(buf);
   }`